# Is there any way to disable intellisense for a specific project / namespace / whatever?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Is there any way to do this at any level other than disabling intellisense in all of Visual Studio? Just wanted to confirm/deny a suspicion about its performance in some of our overly giant projects/solutions while keeping it in other areas that we actually care about.

Comment: ..productivity levels... decreasing... !!! (no, I don't have any useful input.. I've never had to try this..)

Comment: Just FYI, I have a C# class converted/ported from legacy code in a different language which has 7424 members and 51097 lines long. Visual Studio is generally slow doing _stuff_ in that code file but hitting its intellisense is still pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to selectively disable Intellisense. Try disabling it completely and see if that would make a big difference.

Comment: You can manually mark your members/class using the [EditorBrowsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute though I can't say for certain how exactly Visual Studio implements/handles that (it may still do a lot of code analysis just to decide not to show it)

Comment: it's now the end of 2020, almost 8 years from your answer.  Is there still no way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a slow down in Visual Studio on my work machine with several VS extensions installed like Spell Checker. Disabling them helped.