# How to disable Using statement (C#) suggestion in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I am using Visual Studio Code to write C#, however one thing is driving me crazy...

Whenever I want to add a using directive at the top of the file, it keeps suggesting the "Using statement" which results in a using block, when I just wanted to use a namespace.

For example at the top:

[image]

I begin typing a new using line and this always shows up:

[image]

I always inadvertently accept the suggestion due to quickly hitting enter/tab by habit:

[image]

And now I have to manually clean it up ... every time.

So how do I disable this specific suggestion in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!
Extensions are downloaded into (for Windows)

```
c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions
```

This "Using statement" suggestion came with the C# extension.

So inside

```
c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.2\snippets\csharp.json
```

removing the following lines made it go away:

```
"Using statement": {
    "prefix": "using",
    "body": [
        "using (${1:resource})",
        "{",
        "    $0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Using statement"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right then I don't think this can be solved.

Turning a part of Intellisense of is impossible.

[Is there any way to disable intellisense for a specific project / namespace / whatever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468877/is-there-any-way-to-disable-intellisense-for-a-specific-project-namespace-wh)

**EDIT, that is more important than the top part!!:**
Of course there are ways to change the behaviour of intellisense but I'm not really experienced with that.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: Is that also valid for Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are the same.